# Regex to find uncompleted quoted string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some input texts having uncompleted quoted string. I want to find them:

```
Tom said "I don't know why Mary asked me ""who are you?""". Tom told her "I'm Tom 
Mary kept silent. She said ""
Daisy told Tom "I will be there
She told me "She answered ""I met Tom last year""
```

The result expected are:

```
1> "I'm Tom
2> "I will be there
3> "She answered ""I met Tom last year""
```

My pattern is /"(?:[^"]|"")*[^"]$/g

Comment: Just find some pattern, post code and we will help you :)

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like

```
"(?:[^"]|"")*[^"]$
```

It matches an initial `"`, followed by either 1 - a character that isn't a `"`, or 2 - `""` two *quote* characters and finally ended by a character that **isn't** a quote.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/A4sbC6/2).

**Edit**

This is a more complex one, handling multiple quotes on a line, as well as mid sentence quotes

```
^(?:[^"\n]*"(?:[^"\n]|"")*")*[^"\n]*("(?:[^"\n]|"")*)$
```

[Here it is at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/A4sbC6/3).

Comment: It's wonderful. I did the similar thing but it didn't work well as yours. The difference is "gm" flag. Thank you!